# what is the difference between ReactJS convert \r\n in this two way and why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, rendering, newline

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Can someone tell me why, thank you

Is it because one is a text node and another is a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those special characters don't work in HTML, the literal text '\r\n' will be rendered in the browser.

Using the backtick `` ` `` character creates a [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which has a bit more 'syntactic sugar' and functionality than raw HTML text. It is a Javascript string and you can use JS special characters (e.g. `\r\n`) inside it.

HTML uses character encodings instead, which look like this: `&#13;`. This represents the `\n` 'newline' character, and will work in your example.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div>123\r\n123</div>
```

The former one is pure **HTML**, i.e. what is between the opening and closing tags will be displayed *as is*.

```
<div>{'123\r\n123'}</div>
```

Whereas the latter one is **JSX**, where the inner content is a string (programmatically speaking) - notice the use of <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> in the tags - thus `\r` and `\n` being escape characters